# How do I find something starting with something in JSON from requests python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to find a URL in the JSON (request response) that starts with "https://freecash.com/auth/". I want it to only print that and not the other stuff, how can I do this?

The code for the request:

```
z = requests.get(f"https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=readMessage&login={user}&domain={dom}&id={z[c]['id']}").json()
```

And here is where I'm trying to find that exact thing:

```
{z['body']
```

It's not either at the start or the end. how would I search for it? also I need it to only print the URL, not the rest of the response.

Comment: A regex would be a good tool for that.

Comment: Show an extract of the JSON and the context of your pattern and someone will probably have an answer for you. It would help if you could also show the code you're currently executing and the error(s) or unwanted output you're seeing

Answer (score 1):

you can use re module wichis for regex

import re

#Check if the string starts with "http://url1267" and ends with "string_end":

json_response = "The rain in Spain"
x = re.search("^http://url1267.*'string_end'$", json_response)

change the string_end with the exactly in your case

Comment: oh my bad I forgot to mention that it's not either at the start or the end. how would I search for it? also I need it to only print the url, not the rest of the response.

Comment: can you show the response?

Comment: yeah, here is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/Rd6W0fmF

Comment: correct me if i am wrong:
import re

with open("respon.txt", "r") as f:
     content = f.readlines()

default_search = 'https://freecash.com/auth/'

m = re.findall('https://freecash.com/auth/(.+?)</a>', str(content))

for url in m:
    print (default_search + url)

output:

https://freecash.com/auth/verify/58d9b67ceb
https://freecash.com/auth/verify/58d9b67ceb
https://freecash.com/auth/verify/58d9b67ceb

Answer (score 0):

Read your JSON file and then something like:

```py
z = requests.get(f"https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=readMessage&login={user}&domain={dom}&id={z[c]['id']}").json()

for line in z:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('http://url1267'):
        print(line)
```

Comment: It responds with "false" but there are a few lines with a URL that starts like that. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper function that will flatten and iterate through the values in the JSON object:

```
def get_values_from_json(obj):
    if type(obj) is dict:
        for item in obj.values():
            yield from get_values_from_json(item)
    elif type(obj) is list:
        for item in obj:
            yield from get_values_from_json(item)
    else:
        yield obj
```

Then iterate through these, looking for the desired pattern:

```
for item in get_values_from_json(z["body"]):
    if item.startswith("http://url1267"):  # or use regex if this is more complicated
        print(item)
```

EDIT

From a comment on another answer, it's clear that you're actually searching an html page that happens to be part of a JSON request. You can search this using a regex that finds e.g. `freecash.com` within quotation marks (`"` or `'`).

```
import re
for i, item in enumerate(re.findall(r'["\']([^"\']*?freecash\.com[^"\']*?)["\']', z["body"])):
    print(i, item)
```

An alternative and perhaps cleaner solution is to use BeautifulSoup, which will properly parse the html content and look for links in the appropriate contexts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(z["body"], features="lxml")
for tag in soup.find_all("a"):
    link = tag.get("href")
    if "freecash.com" in link:
        print(link)
```

Comment: doesn't print anything, thats weird. what should I do?

Comment: @pylol None of the solutions here print anything?

Comment: yeah, that's weird, does it work for you?

Comment: this is the code im using: https://pastebin.com/Mbi0CMK5
I tried bs4 too, doesn't print anything 
and heres the json response: https://pastebin.com/dYSFE3iz

Comment: By 'json response' do you mean the content of `z["body"]`? Yes it should work. [This is what should get picked up by the regex](https://regex101.com/r/UCrXO9/1)

Comment: yes, it gives me no response.

Comment: Pretty sure your `z["body"]` somehow does not contain the html content you are showing in pastebin. Can you paste the first 500 characters verbatim into your question?

Comment: hi! sorry for the late response, but it works. the only problem is that the url i'm trying to find is in  the same line as the url it prints, i'm guessing it doesnt print because of that. how would I get the 2nd url? heres the line: "href="http://url1267.mail.freecash.com/ls/click?upn=V34YZAMjhmWbaKu97agC-3D">https://freecash.com/auth/verify/72e42f6315</a> "that's probably why it doesnt give me a response, i was searching for "freecash.com/auth/verify". could you help me make it only print the url starting with "freecash.com/auth/verify"?